# Google sheet publish to web from sheets android app or by script.google.com

Tags: android, google-apps-script, tabletop.js

Hi I'm developing an application which accesses script.google.com to create google sheet and mail the sheet link to my employees makes them a way to update daily reports from home which I'll fetch using TableTop. But I'm currently stuck on Publish to web option which is a mandatory thing on tabletop. Publish to web is quite easy using a PC(in a computer browser) but I don't know how to do the same in Google Sheets Android app. I'm preferring android app as most of my employees don't have a proper pc. or it would be nice if there is a way to Publish to web from script.google.com. Please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible as of the moment. even the official help center [Make Google Docs, Sheets, Slides & Forms public](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1) directs users to use the web interface via browser to publish docs.

Comment: Thanks pal!! atleast I could think of other ways in peace:)

Comment: Thanks, if this helped you. Consider choosing the answer or upvoting it to help others who may be dealing with the same issue.